# change state both on mousemove and on click

Tags: javascript, click, mousemove

I have this javascript that hides a div after 4 seconds of inactivity.

```
var timeout;
var isHidden = false;

function hideOnIdle() {
if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    if (!isHidden) {
        document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = "0";
        isHidden = true;
    }
}, 4000);
if (isHidden) {
    document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = "1";
    isHidden = false;
}
}

if (document.addEventListener) {
document.addEventListener("mousemove", hideOnIdle);
} else {
document.attachEvent("mousemove", hideOnIdle);
}
```

This will show the div again if you move the mouse.

How can I modify the javascript and show the div again also on click?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lcqumf2y/

Thanks.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("click", hideOnIdle);`

Comment: that will change only if you click, I want both @adeneo

Comment: Then you use both, you can only add one event in each listener

Answer (score 0):

I changed your JsFiddle example:

```js
var timeout;
var isHidden = false;

function hideOnIdle() {
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        if (!isHidden) {
            hide();
        }
    }, 4000);
    if (isHidden) {
        show();
    }
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = "0";
    isHidden = true;
}

function show() {
    document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = "1";
    isHidden = false;
}

if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", hideOnIdle);
    document.addEventListener("click", hideonIdle);
} else {
    document.attachEvent("mousemove", hideOnIdle);
}
```

```css
#slide {
    transition: all .2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide">ABC123</div>
```